# Call specific function a few seconds after C++/QML application start

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I am currently working on a C++ application with QML files.
I would like to have start screen on my application for a few seconds, and then get my main page. But I can't find any information on a proper way to do so in QML, using a specific event or such :(

My question is: what would be the proper way to do so in QML? If there is non, how could I nicely get this working in C++.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Timer](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtqml/qml-qtquick2-timer.html) in QML and load the main screen when it is triggered.